# Open stand alone SDK Manager manually

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

While searching its found that stand alone SDK Manager is deprecated on Android studio 2.3. Is there any possibilities to open the stand alone SDK Manager manually?

Answer (score 0):

Just a command line interface is still available (in tools/bin/sdkmanager). Below it's usage message:

```
Usage: 
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file <file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]

In its first form, installs, or uninstalls, or updates packages.
    By default, the listed packages are installed or (if already installed)
    updated to the latest version.

    --uninstall: uninstalled listed packages.

    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
    with explicit paths.

In its second form (with --update), all installed packages are
    updated to the latest version.

In its third form, all installed and available packages are printed
    out.

In its fourth form (with --licenses), show and offer the option to
     accept licenses for all available packages that have not already been
     accepted.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK 
                              containing this tool

    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.

    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.

    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.

    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.

    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
```

Answer (score 0):

**standalone** SDK Manager is no more available in the **2.3.0** or above versions of android studio.